# Is there a way to write selinium automation code more elegantly?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

framework: selinium chrom driver ; mostly use xpaths to automate UI

My code currently looks like this:

```
public void Delete_calendar()
        {
            Logger.Info("Deleting calendar with name provided");
            _login.SelectOLC(ws);
            ws.WaitForCheckPoint("Scheduling");
            ws.ClickByXPath("//nav/a/span");
            ws.waitforStatus("//ia-action-menu-item");
            ws.ClickByXPath("(//input[@type='text'])[5]");
            ws.ClickByXPath("//text()[contains(.,'Default')]/ancestor::li[1]");
            ws.waitforStatus("//button[text()='Assign']");
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            ws.ClickByXPath("//nav/a/span");
            ws.ClickByXPath("//ia-action-menu-item");
            ws.ClickByXPath("(//a[contains(text(),'Calendars')])[2]");
            ws.ClickByXPath("//input[@type='text']");
            ws.waitforStatus("//span[text()='Sys_demo']");
            ws.ClickByXPath("(//button[@type='button'])[2]");
            ws.ClickByXPath("//ia-action-menu-item[contains(text(),'Delete')]");
            // ws.ClickByXPath("(//button[@type='button'])[30]");
            ws.ClickByXPath("/html/body/ia-dialog/ia-dialog-footer/ia-button[2]/button");
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

...
All the ws.Clickby are the selinium call method, is there a way i can put all this xpaths or the code in a external file and just call that file and it executes the same way it does above.
basicallly i want my code to look elegant and less buckly and easy to read.
Any suggestion is welcome.

my idea i had in mind is

external file  '`test.txt`'

```
public void Delete_calendar()
        {
            Logger.Info("Deleting calendar with name provided");
            _login.SelectOLC(ws);
            RunSeliniumcodefromExternalfile("test.txt")

        }

        test.txt file contains
        [
        ws.WaitForCheckPoint("Scheduling");
            ws.ClickByXPath("//nav/a/span");
            ws.waitforStatus("//ia-action-menu-item");
            ws.ClickByXPath("(//input[@type='text'])[5]");
            ws.ClickByXPath("//text()[contains(.,'Default')]/ancestor::li[1]");
            ws.waitforStatus("//button[text()='Assign']");
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            ws.ClickByXPath("//nav/a/span");
            ws.ClickByXPath("//ia-action-menu-item");
            ws.ClickByXPath("(//a[contains(text(),'Calendars')])[2]");
            ws.ClickByXPath("//input[@type='text']");
            ws.waitforStatus("//span[text()='Sys_demo']");
            ws.ClickByXPath("(//button[@type='button'])[2]");
            ws.ClickByXPath("//ia-action-menu-item[contains(text(),'Delete')]");
            // ws.ClickByXPath("(//button[@type='button'])[30]");
            ws.ClickByXPath("/html/body/ia-dialog/ia-dialog-footer/ia-button[2]/button");
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can incorporate the Page Object Model pattern. POM allows you to defined IWebElements and mark them with their locator at class level. Using this technique, actions on the webelements are carried out without specifying the locator for each action.

Below is an example of how you can achieve this with your provided code for the Delete_Calendar method.

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;

namespace POMExample.PageObjects
{
    public class POMExample
    {
        private IWebDriver driver;
        private WebDriverWait wait;

        public POMExample(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            this.driver = driver;
            wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

            //This line instantiates the Iwebelements marked with the FindsBy attribute.
            PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);
        }

        //The FindsBy attribute allows you to tag an IWebelement with a locator.
        [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//nav/a/span")]
        private IWebElement elem_1;

        [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "(//input[@type='text'])[5]")]
        private IWebElement elem_2;

        public void Delete_calendar()
        {
            //Instead of: ws.ClickByXPath("//nav/a/span");
            elem_1.Click();

            //Instead of: ws.ClickByXPath("(//input[@type='text'])[5]");
            elem_2.Click();

            //and so on...
        }
    }
}
```

If you are still keen on using external sources for storing your locators I would further add that generally using property files to store locators is popular but not necessarily best practice, please refer to https://seleniumjava.com/2017/03/19/do-not-store-element-locators-in-property-files/ for further information.

Comment: I believe POM is not supported with .net core just as an fyi.

Comment: Page object model is a pattern, PageFactory.InitElements is indeed not supported in .net core but you can still implement the pattern in different ways such as [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47035004/is-there-any-alternative-for-pagefactory-using-net-core).

Adding to this, you can still write your own object initializer using reflection. This means one can write a custom attribute which is picked up by the said object initializer the same way that PageFactory's InitElements method picks class properties marked with the "FindsBy" attribute.